# DataTemplate binding grid background through a converter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, converters

I have a problem for a while with a data binding that changes the color of a grid and somehow it doesn't work.
Iv'e put a break point in the converter and the application hit it, but still the background color of the grid doesn't change and it stays as there is no background color defined...

here is my code:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ResultsUserControls}"
          Background="{x:Null}"
          BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid Width="200"
            Height="70"
            Background="{Binding CurrentResult,Converter={StaticResource crawlerTypeToResultColorConverter}}">
        <Label Content="{Binding .CurrentResult.SourceUrl}" />
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

and the converter:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Brushes.Red;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
```

Comment: In your case, there is no need to use data binding, you can directly set Background="Red", why bother?

Comment: I want to use a condition inside the converter and returned the red only to check if the converter workes...

Comment: I suggest using [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to see if the colour is actually being changed the way you think it is. Perhaps it's hidden by another element? Do you have any binding errors in the Output window? You can get more information about bindings by going to 'Debug' menu > 'Options and Settings...', then look under 'Debugging' > 'Output Window' and adjust the output levels under 'WPF Trace Settings'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                      System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return Binding.DoNothing;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tinkered with your code, and what you have should work.  As an experiment, delete CurrentResult from your binding for Background:

```
<Grid Width="200" Height="70" Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource crawlerTypeToResultColorConverter}}">
```

I suspect you will see your red background now.  I noticed that if the XAML parser can't find the property that you're binding to (because it's misspelled or just doesn't exist) it won't do the conversion.  I would guess that the XAML parser isn't able to find CurrentResult on your items.

Comment: why is that? Then what property is he binding to?